# How to add data to Firestore in android using MVP Architecture?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

so currently I'm trying to use MVP Architecture for my latest project in android. I use firestore as its server to store all the data. The problem is when I try to input data from my activity which contains the logic to store the data to firestore, it worked, but when I do it with MVP Architecture, the save button didn't store the data to firestore collection. How is this possible? because the query I use in both cases is the same.

**Here's my Activity with MVP Architecture:**

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId){
            R.id.nav_save -> {
                val stringTitle = edtTitle.text.toString()
                val stringContent = edtContent.text.toString()
                if (stringTitle.isEmpty() && stringContent.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "your note shouldn't be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    return false
                }
                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                mPresenter.performAdd(stringTitle, stringContent,this)
                return true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

**This one is my mPresenter:**

```
class AddPresenter: AddContract.Presenter, AddContract.onAddListener {

    private val mAddView: AddContract.View? = null
    private var mAddInteractor: AddInteractor? = null

    override fun performAdd(title: String, content: String, context: Context) {
       mAddInteractor?.Add(title, content, context)
    }
}
```

**This one is my Interactor:**

```
class AddInteractor(onAddListener: AddContract.onAddListener) : AddContract.Interactor {
    val firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
    val documentReference: DocumentReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("mainCollection").document(firebaseUser.uid).collection("subCollection").document()
    private var mOnAddListener: AddContract.onAddListener

    init {
        this.mOnAddListener = onAddListener
    }

    override fun Add(title: String, content: String, context: Context) {
        var note: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap<String, Any>()
        note.put("title", title)
        note.put("content", content)
        documentReference.set(note).addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully saved! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error save, caused by : " + it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

**This one is my Contract:**

```
interface AddContract {
    interface View{
    }
    interface Interactor{
        fun Add(title: String, content: String, context: Context)
    }
    interface Presenter{
        fun performAdd(title: String, content: String, context: Context)
    }
    interface onAddListener{
    }
}
```

Comment: in your presenter, when you call the method `mAddInteractor?.Add(title, content, context)`, are you sure your `mAddInteractor` is not null and that the `Add()` method is being called?

Comment: @Ryan if I use toast to check my input, it's not null, but i don't know why the interactor is not working

Comment: @Ryan is there any way to check whether I call it correctly?

Comment: glad to see you solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Basically, my activity didn't know which interactor it should be called, so instead of initializing the interactor and the view with a null value, I decided to reformat the structure like this:

```
class AddPresenter(addView: AddNoteContract.View): AddContract.Presenter, AddContract.onAddListener {

    private val mAddView: AddContract.View
    private val mAddInteractor: AddInteractor

    init {
        this.mAddView = addView
        mAddInteractor = AddInteractor(this)
    }
    override fun performAdd(title: String, content: String, context: Context) {
       mAddInteractor?.Add(title, content, context)
    }
}
```